# Cold Fusion - New Server - Too many client tasks

Tags: coldfusion, ms-access-2016, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to fine tune a ColdFsuion 2016 server.

On new Virtual Machine every once in awhile I am getting a:
Error Executing Database Query.[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too many client tasks.

I am going through many configurations and performance updates etc and trying to be sure the server settings are the same.  Links here included for references.

New VMachine:
AMD EPVC 7542 32-Core Processor @ 2.9 GHz
Memory: 4 GB
Windows Server 2016 : 64 bit
ColdFusion 2016
Data Connection: 1GB Down and 1 GB Up

Database Used: MS Access (I know but Access works fine - lol)

I was running Windows 2012 Server with ColdFusion 2016 : and rarely had any issues.

Previous VMachine:
Intel Xeon X5660 @ 2.8 GHz (2 processors)
Memory: 45 GB (about 6GB used)
Windows Server 2012 : 64 bit
ColdFusion 2016
Data Connection: 1GB Down and 100mb Up (don't care about Download)

Database Used: MS Access (I know but Access works fine - lol)

Is there a way to see if potentially there is a different database driver on old vs new machine.
Is this a server memory issue? Thoughts anyone.

Error Executing Database Query.[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too many client tasks.

Some performance fine tuning links.  I am doing all suggested and recommended settings. And also looking at previous settings in CF Admin.

https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/03/coldfusion-performance-issues-and-optimization/

https://www.cfguide.io/coldfusion-administrator/

Comment: Found this in the Server Log: The description for Event ID 0 from source ColdFusion 2016 ODBC Server cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/bugs-fixed-coldfusion-2016-update-9.html#knownissues

Comment: Is that a recent event or an old one? Because the issue description refers to the odbc services  not starting at all, instead of connections being limited. I don't use odbc. What datasource settings does the CF Admin provide for socket connections - beyond the dsn name? A search says the error is usually caused by too many open connections, which could be a limitation of Access or something else.  [What are the odbc versions in win2012 vs 2016?](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/analytics-automation-software/data-virtualization/200356-How-can-I-determine-the-version-of-the-O.html)

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search on "[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too many client tasks." turns up a number of issues related to the fact that MS Access is a desktop application and not suited for a web server. It may just "work fine" for development, but it is a liability in a production environment.

You may be able to find a short-term solution for this problem, but the only real fix is to convert your database to MySQL or SQL Server depending on your needs.

Comment: As related. It does work just fine. Been working fine for 20+ yrs. It starts not working fine when other think they do not work fine. And an update comes down the pipe, forgetting about the other stuff working just fine.  Then throw more money at it, to fix or buy new.. Lol...

Comment: Like it or not, Access is not an enterprise database and has different limitations than one. As you don't seem interested in upgrading, investigating connection and driver settings would be the next logical step.  Determine if the error is something you can control. It may not be. What are your current CF DSN settings, including any advanced settings? What are the [odbc versions of both servers?](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/analytics-automation-software/data-virtualization/200356-How-can-I-determine-the-version-of-the-O.html)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem lately under XAMPP/Apache/PHP.. found that php.ini was maintaining persistent connections even though I wasn't requesting them.. may be a similar configuration issue for ColdFusion. in php.ini, it was under odbc configuration. Never worked with Cold Fusion, but hope this helps.
Really odd, only happened when I reinstalled the Microsoft Access Redistributable driver this week to roll back an upgrade that caused more problems than good.